# How read file paths mentioned in a text file inside a Korn shell script?

Tags: shell-script, grep, scripting

I am writing a script to read multiple log files and find lines with a specific string. However I am getting an error when trying to egrep/grep on the file.

I have a file that has the names of the log files to read (see below)

**files.txt**

```
./code_a.log
./code_b.log
```

**log_analysis.ksh**

```
#!/bin/ksh

platform=$1
lw_platform=$(echo "$platform" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
log_dir="/project/$lw_platform/logs/"
read_file="/user/LogAnalysis/files.txt"
out_file="/user/LogAnalysis/out3.txt"

echo $lw_platform
echo $log_dir

while -r line; do

    echo "Began: $line" >> $out_file

    cd ${log_dir}
    echo $(pwd)

    egrep -n 'ERROR:' $line >> $out_file

    echo "End: $line" >> $out_file

done < $read_file
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
test 
/project/test/logs/ 
/project/test/logs 
.grep: 0652-033 Cannot open ./code_a.log
```

However I don't get this error if I run the same `egrep` command directly into the shell. Proves that I have the permissions to read the file.

Comment: Note that you seem to assume that `code_a.log` and `code_b.log` are available in the script's current directory.  If that is not the case, then either update the text file with the full absolute path of the files, or `cd` in the scirpt to the correct directory before reading from the file.

Comment: In the script I cd to log_dir which is where these log files are present.

Comment: Is the error message prefixed by a single dot, as you have shown? Has the file that you are reading from been edited on a Windows system previous to having been transferred to your AIX system? Does the `cd` in the script actually succeed? What is the full output of the script when you encounter the error?

Comment: Yes the error message is prefixed by a single dot. The file that I am reading from has been edited in windows before transferring to UNIX server. The `cd` succeeds (I did `pwd` to check).

Comment: The script runs fine if I hard code the filename in egrep command. I get the desired output in the `out_file`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the complete output of the script.

Comment: I used dos2unix to convert the file, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by converting the file from dos line endings to UNIX format. I used the following command.

```
dos2unix files.txt
```